# Why does adding a reference in this CRTP base function call remove errors?

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference, crtp

I've been experimenting recently with using the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern to implement a variety of Matrix classes and came across some behavior I don't understand.

When I have

```
    template <class T> double& MatrixBase<T>::operator()(int row, int col)
{
     return static_cast<T&>(*this).operator()(row, col);
}
```

I have no errors.  If I have

```
            template <class T> double& MatrixBase<T>::operator()(int row, int col)
{
    return static_cast<T>(*this).operator()(row, col);
}
```

I get this error message:

```
src/matrices.cpp:15:12: error: no matching conversion for stati
c_cast from 'nav::MatrixBase<nav::Matrix>' to 'nav::Matrix'
    return static_cast<T>(*this).operator()(row, col);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/matrices.cpp:122:24: note: in instantiation of member funct
ion 'nav::MatrixBase<nav::Matrix>::operator()' requested here
        dm(pos, pos) = operator()(pos, pos);
                       ^
src/matrices.cpp:636:23: note: in instantiation of member funct
ion 'nav::MatrixBase<nav::Matrix>::toDiagonalMatrix' requested here
        *this = thisAsMatrix.toDiagonalMatrix();
                             ^
src/matrices.h:85:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit
copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'nav::MatrixBase<nav::Mat
rix>' to 'const nav::Matrix' for 1st argument
class Matrix : public MatrixBase<Matrix>
      ^
src/matrices.cpp:199:9: note: candidate constructor not viable:
 requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
Matrix::Matrix() : rows_{}, cols_{}, data_{}
        ^
src/matrices.cpp:206:9: note: candidate constructor not viable:
 requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
Matrix::Matrix(int num_rows, int num_cols)
```

What strikes me as particularly odd is that other members of my MatrixBase/Matrix classes do not have T as a reference yet throw no errors.

Below is more of the code used:

```
template <class T> double& MatrixBase<T>::operator()(int row, int col)
{
    return static_cast<T&>(*this).operator()(row, col);
}

template <class T> double MatrixBase<T>::operator()(int row, int col) const
{
    return static_cast<T>(*this).operator()(row, col);
}

template <class T> T& MatrixBase<T>::operator=(double value)
{
    return static_cast<T>(*this).operator=(value);
}

template <class T> T& MatrixBase<T>::operator=(T& a)
{
    return static_cast<T>(*this).operator=(a);
}

// Add another derived Matrix to this derived Matrix
template <class T> T& MatrixBase<T>::operator+=(T& a)
{
    return static_cast<T>(*this).operator+=(a);
}


double& Matrix::operator()(int row, int col)
{
    REQUIRE(row >= 0 && col >= 0, "Error: Indices must be non-negative.");
    REQUIRE(row < rows_ && col < cols_, "Error: Element index outside matrix.");
    return data_[row][col];
}

double Matrix::operator()(int row, int col) const
{
    REQUIRE(row >= 0 && col >= 0, "Error: Indices must be non-negative.");
    REQUIRE(row < rows_ && col < cols_, "Error: Element index outside matrix.");
    return data_[row][col];
}

/*****************************************************************************
 *   Purpose:  Initializes the whole matrix to the specified value.
 ******************************************************************************/
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(double value)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows_; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols_; j++)
        {
            data_[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

/*****************************************************************************
*   Purpose:  Copies one matrix to another.
******************************************************************************/
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& a)
{
    int iteratedRows = 0;
    while(iteratedRows < a.rows())
    {
        if(this->rows() - 1 < iteratedRows)
        {
            this->data_.push_back(pfstl::VectorN<double, kMaxDimension>());
            this->rows_++; // we added a new row
        }
        int iteratedCols = 0;
        while(iteratedCols < a.cols())
        {
            if(this->cols() - 1 < iteratedCols)
            {
                this->data_[iteratedRows].push_back(a(iteratedRows, iteratedCols));
            }
            else
            {
                this->data_[iteratedRows][iteratedCols] = a(iteratedRows, iteratedCols);
            }
            iteratedCols++;
        }
        iteratedRows++;
    }
    // if a has less rows than this, force this to have the same # of rows as a
    while(a.rows() < this->rows_)
    {
        // In order to make the sizes equal, remove excess rows from this from the back
        this->data_.erase(end(this->data_));
        this->rows_--;
    }
    // Same logic as above for columns
    while(a.cols() < this->cols_)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this->rows_; i++)
        {
            this->data_[i].erase(end(this->data_[i]));
        }
        this->cols_--;
    }

    this->rows_ = a.rows();
    this->cols_ = a.cols();

    return *this;
}

// Add another derived Matrix to this derived Matrix
Matrix& Matrix::operator+=(const Matrix& a)
{

    REQUIRE(rows_ == a.rows(), "Error: Matrix addition requires same number of rows.");
    REQUIRE(cols_ == a.cols(), "Error: Matrix addition requires same number of columns.");

    for(int i = 0; i < a.rows(); i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < a.cols(); k++)
        {
            data_[i][k] += a(i, k);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Header File:

```
template <typename T> class MatrixBase
{
public:
    // These methods must be implemented for each deriving class

    double& operator()(int row, int col);
    double operator()(int row, int col) const;

    T& operator=(double value);
    T& operator=(T& a);

    // Add another derived Matrix to this derived Matrix
    T& operator+=(T& a);
}

class Matrix : public MatrixBase<Matrix>
{
public:
    // Constructors
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int row, int cols);
    // Destructor
    ~Matrix();

    double& operator()(int row, int col);
    double operator()(int row, int col) const;

    Matrix& operator=(double value);
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& a);

    // Add another derived Matrix to this derived Matrix
    Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix& a);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting to a value type creates a new object, in this case one which requires a `Matrix` constructor taking a `MatrixBase`. No such constructor exists in your code.

Casting to a reference type just gives you the original object, referred to in another way.

I can only imagine the other functions don't generate the same error because they are never instantiated, but I admit I didn't read through all of your (very long) sample code.

Here's a short testcase that demonstrates, fundamentally, the casting behaviour (albeit with a cast to the same class, so look out for the copy constructor):

```
struct NotCopyable
{
    NotCopyable() {}
    NotCopyable(const NotCopyable&) = delete;
};

template <typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
    (void)static_cast<T>(t);
}

template <typename T>
void bar(T& t)
{
    (void)static_cast<T&>(t);
}

int main()
{
    NotCopyable c;
    foo(c);
    bar(c);
}
```

It fails with the same error, but if you comment out `foo` then it succeeds because that function template no longer needs to be instantiated. `bar` always succeeds.

Here's that example again, this time modified to be one step closer to your original code, by introducing an inheritance relationship and a *missing* candidate constructor in `Derived`:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : Base {};

template <typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
    (void)static_cast<Derived>(t);
}

template <typename T>
void bar(T& t)
{
    (void)static_cast<Derived&>(t);
}

int main()
{
    Derived c;
    foo<Base>(c);
    bar<Base>(c);
}
```

Again, comment out the `foo<Base>(c)` call and the whole program will build.

The irony is that the constructor isn't really "missing" because it shouldn't exist; it's just that you shouldn't be trying to create a new value in the first place. The cast to reference is correct.